# What is the protocol for loading test suites for both nose and unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, doctest

I used the `unittest` `load_tests()` protocol, because I want my automated tests to include a `doctest` but only for one module. This works fine when discovered and run by unittest, but fails when instead run by `nose`.

```
import doctest
import unittest

import my.module

suite = doctest.DocTestSuite(my.module)

def load_tests(loader, std, pat): # invoked by unittest discovery process
    return suite
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/g/data/w85/brl654/conda/envs/haz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
TypeError: load_tests() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

If I make those arguments optional, will `nose` run the tests? Is there a better way to integrate this test suite, so that it can be run by either `unittest` or by `nose`?

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is that `nosetests` normally searches for a combination of both `unittest.TestCase` subclasses and functions with test-like names. A `unittest.TestSuite` is neither a `TestCase` subclass nor a function, so it cannot naturally be picked up by nose. (Furthermore, nose erroneously does pick up `load_tests` and try to run it *as a test function*, contrary to unittest's test-loading protocol.)

A crude solution is:

```py
load_tests.__test__ = False # instruct nose to skip load_tests()
def test_with_nose():
    assert suite.run(unittest.TestResult()).wasSuccessful()
```